# Lógica de un sistema de citas

Tags: php, sql, angular

Necesito realizar un sistema de citas, en el cual tengo 3 grupos. Cada grupo puede dar citas de distinto rango de tiempo

- Médicos - Citas de 30 minutos, pero pueden dar de más siempre de 15min en 15min
- Psicólogos - Citas de 45 minutos, pero pueden dar de más siempre de 15min en 15min
- Primera cita - Citas de 90 minutos, pero pueden dar de más siempre de 15min en 15min

Mi lógica hasta ahora es la siguiente, pongamos que trabajan 8 horas, en minutos son 480 minutos.

Ahora podemos hacer bloques de 15 minutos por ejemplo los médicos serían 2 grupos de 15 minutos hasta llegar a 30 minutos, los psicólogos 3 bloques de 15 minutos hasta llegar a 45 y así sucesivamente...

Entonces tendría 32 bloques al día por cada médico, psicólogo o que seleccione.

Como puedo hacer que las horas se vayan ordenando conforme asigno bloques si la hora de comienzo son las 08:00 y la hora de fin 16:00, como puedo sacar los rangos de horas.

El diseño que tengo es el siguiente

[image]

Donde está la hora le indicaría de cuanto voy a dar las citas en este caso de 00:30h y abajo donde aparece el input date le diría el día que quiero dar la fecha para que me cargue las citas de ese día

Comment: Primero date una vuelta en [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Como podras ver debes agregar una pregunta en especifico, pegar parte del codigo que llevas y describir el problema. Modifica tu pregunta seguro que usaras php y angular?

Comment: @MiguelZarate Uso PHP para la API REST y lo demás lo tengo en en Angular, y la base de datos en MySQL, no puedo agregar código puesto que solo tengo el diseño

Comment: Entonces cual es la pregunta?, la conexion a api, la muestra de las citas, el guardado de una cita, el alta de un terapeuta, o de un usuario...

Comment: @MiguelZarate - Como puedo hacer que las horas se vayan ordenando conforme asigno bloques si la hora de comienzo son las 08:00 y la hora de fin 16:00, como puedo sacar los rangos de horas?

Comment: Primero inicia con lo sencillo, por ejemplo citas de 30 min, muestras tu horario de 8 a 16 todas en verde, despues cargas de bd los horarios ocupados. Genera todo el flujo solo para este caso y despues agregas los 15 min extra. Has ejercicios en una hoja de calculo a mano, para que vayas identificando todos tus elementos en el sistema, Paciente, Doctor, Citas , Calendario, etc.